# pg-promise spy on query functions

Tags: javascript, pg-promise

Is it possible to spy on pg-promise's query functions (`query()`, `one()`, `none()`, ...)?

The following example fails with the error message `TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'none' of object '[object Object]'`:

```js
const db = pgPromise()({ /* ... */ });

jest.spyOn(db, 'none');
```

Using `jest.spyOn(db, 'none', 'get');` does not work either.

Comment: Check out [noLocking](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/module-pg-promise.html) initialization option ;)